# How to keep two projects info in one google-services.json for receiving FCM Notifications from multiple senders

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

When we have to two Notification Senders then we will also have two firebase projects per sender.

The firebase documentation clearly describes how to fetch  Token by SENDER ID for the multiple senders but the confusing part is

*How come we can combine two projects in one **google-services.json** file when we have multiple projects per SENDER ID.*

*Firebase console does not allow to add the same SH1 twice for two different projects*

Comment: Have you got any solution for the same ??? How you are dealing with multiple sender id ??

Comment: I could not find any reliable answer for this. I gave up on that idea. But I think you can achieve this if you implement your own notification handling at a lower level instead of using Fabric SDK based solution which relays on google-services.json configurations.